# Parsley Remote - prevent saving validated values

Tags: jquery, validation, parsley.js

Is there any way to prevent parsley remote (version 2.0) to save already validated values?

I know that is useful to avoid unnecessary ajax calls but I use it for checking is email unique when creating users and since users are added via ajax this happens:

1) email passes validation and user is created

2) same email passes validation again even though there is user with that email now because previous result was saved

EDIT: This happens even when I add [OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")] to my email validation api (I use ASP .NET MVC 4).

Answer (score 0):

managed to get this using:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#Submit').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#Form").parsley().asyncValidate()
                .done(function () {
                    console.log("validation success");
                    //$('#Form').parsley().destroy(); // this is the trick, works with either
                    $('#User').parsley().destroy();

                })
                .fail(function () {
                    console.log("validation failed");
                });
        });
    });
```

and my html is

```
    <form id="Form" data-parsley-validate>
    <input type='text'
           data-parsley-required="true"
           data-parsley-remote='http://echo.jsontest.com/key/value'
           id='User'
           name='User' /><br/>
    <input type='text'
           data-parsley-required='true'
           id='Email'
           name='Email' /><br/>
    <input type='submit'
           id='Submit'
           name='Submit' />
</form>
```

this other dude also got the same solution for a similar issue: [Parsley.js Submit form not working when using addAsyncValidator and remote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25763943/parsley-js-submit-form-not-working-when-using-addasyncvalidator-and-remote)

Comment: Unfortunately it's not working for me. Maybe because I create parsley from js and don't use data-parsley-validate.

parsleyForm = $('#userPanel').parsley({...});

Comment: that would be the same thing tho.. maybe try to .reset() the said field or form? these are the only 2 available methods i can see on http://parsleyjs.org/doc/#psly-usage-field

Comment: I tried both of them but still not working.  Which version of parsley did you use?

Comment: 2.0.5 ~ latest as of time of writing. try my example, i swear it worked ;)